# Something with generics spring boot and multiple implementations of a service interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics

this is actually working, but sonar complains about not using generics ..
I tried my best to handle this but....

The Problem itself:

first of all I have an interface of a service:

```
public interface QueueMessageReceiver<T extends QueueMessage> {

    boolean onMessage(T queueMessage);

    Class<T> getQueueMessageType();

}
```

compiles nice an smooth with generics

second I have several Services that implements that interface
I added one example, there are more (3 more)

```
@Component
public class DBoxCreateMessageReceiver implements QueueMessageReceiver<DBoxCreateMessageDTO> {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseService databaseService;

    @Override
    public boolean onMessage(DBoxCreateMessageDTO queueMessage) {
        String uuid = databaseService.createMessage(queueMessage);
        if (uuid == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public Class<DBoxCreateMessageDTO> getQueueMessageType() {
        return DBoxCreateMessageDTO.class;
    }

}
```

DBoxCreateMessageDTO extends of course QueueMessage

next I have a component which holds all Service implementations
and decides on incoming message type which implementation has to deal with the current message

queueMessageReceivers gets all Implementing Components via Spring autowireing

but i have a compile error on the line:
`queueMessageReceiver.onMessage(queueMessage)`
which says:
The method onMessage(capture#3-of ?) in the type QueueMessageReceiver<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (QueueMessage)

```
    @Autowired
    private QueueMessageReceiver<?>[] queueMessageReceivers;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean onMessage(QueueMessage queueMessage) {
        for (QueueMessageReceiver<?> queueMessageReceiver : queueMessageReceivers) {
            if (queueMessageReceiver.getQueueMessageType().equals(queueMessage.getClass())) {
                return queueMessageReceiver.onMessage(queueMessage);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

what is the right way, to call the explicit implementation in this generic implementation?

If I remove all generics from the Classes it works pretty well, but sonar complains about code smells...
So if someone knows how to deal with that WITH generics , would be help full.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Using `<T extends QueueMessage>` only guarantees you that you'll read a `QueueMessage` not any subtype.
More info and explanation here [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Therefor the

```
boolean onMessage(T queueMessage);
```

should be

```
boolean onMessage(QueueMessage queueMessage);
```

and

```
@Autowired
private QueueMessageReceiver<?>[] queueMessageReceivers;
```

should be

```
@Autowired
private QueueMessageReceiver<? extends QueueMessage>[] queueMessageReceivers;
```

and in receivers, cast the object to what you need

```
@Override
    public boolean onMessage(DBoxCreateMessageDTO queueMessage) {
        String uuid = databaseService.createMessage(queueMessage);
```

to

```
@Override
    public boolean onMessage(QueueMessage queueMessage) {
        DBoxCreateMessageDTO d = (DBoxCreateMessageDTO) queueMessage;
        String uuid = databaseService.createMessage(d);
```